# Chrome Extension for content-padding

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, browser-extension

I recently got a really really nice sidebar for chrome but sadly when openened it spans over the website content, so I quickly learned some browser extensions basics and even got it to work on most pages, I just add padding to the body, and the sidebar no more spans over content, in theory.

That works on most of the pages however not om certain sites like youtube.com, wikipedia.com, reddit.com, i discovered.

Has some more advanced dev any ideas to improve to make this work on all pages?

```
// content.js

const currentDomain = window.location.hostname;

if (currentDomain.includes("wikipedia.org")) {
 console.log("Error Site is Wikipedia")
} else {

 document.body.style.paddingLeft = '60px';

}
```

```
{
 "manifest_version": 3,
 "name": "Sidebar Helper",
 "description": "Adds spacing to make sidebars not overlap website content.",
 "version": "1.0.1",
 "icons": {
 "48": "icon.png"
 },
 "action": {
 "default_title": "Sidebar Helper",
 "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
 },
 "permissions": ["activeTab", "storage"],
 "host_permissions": [],
 "background": {
 "service_worker": "service-worker.js"
 },
 "content_scripts": [{
 "js": ["content.js"],
 "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
 }]
}
```

service-worker: empty
popup: not really used

I tried various styles manually to body.
For example on wikipedia it kinda works, the spacing works, but is after the sidebar and now to the full left.

I expect it to work on all pages.

Comment: There's no reliable/universal solution for content scripts. Use the new [sidePanel](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/sidePanel/) API instead.

Comment: The thing is the sidebar is not coded by me, so I cannot change itself to use that api, so I think that won't really be possible.

Comment: Please clarify your comment as it's unclear how it's related.

Comment: I cannot use the sidebar api. As I downloaded an extension from the webstore, but it overlapped content so I wanted to make an extension that moves the website content to the right, so the extensions sidebar does not overlapp content. Due to this i cannot use the sidebar api, as I'm not the developer of the sidebar. Nor would adding an empty sidebar change anything.

Comment: Unfortuntely it's still unclear why you can't use the API, so I'll try to guess: if you want to display another site you can do it inside an iframe.